# Is there a way to walk an XML tree in Elm?

Tags: html, xml, elm

If I have XML data that I'm trying to make into Elm Html, is there a way to walk an XML tree, looking for an element that could be anywhere in that tree? For example, I'd like to take this incoming xml:

```xml
<root>
  <arbitrary>
    <numberOfTagsHere>
      <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here. May contain <tag foo="bar">some text</tag></p>
      <p>Maybe another paragraph here.</p>
    </numberOfTagsHere>
  </arbitrary>
</root>
```

and make something like this:

```xml
<html>
  <div class="arbitrary">
  <div class="numberOfTagsHere">
    <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here. May contain <span class="foo bar">some text</span></p>
    <p>Maybe another paragraph here.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Is that beyond the scope of Elm? Should I just switch to XSLT instead?

I see that there are XML parsing libraries like [this one](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/ymtszw/elm-xml-decode/latest/), but I don't really see a way to walk a tree, transforming tags along the way.

Comment: Certainly it is possible to walk the tree. You need a definition of the tree, perhaps as a record structure, and then you need to decide what to do with each node as you find it. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

The library you mentioned is a decoder, but I'd suggest you use the underlying parser here.

You can use `elm/parser` to build your own parser that outputs a tree you can easily walk down and output either `Html` or a string representing html. Alternatively you can use one that's already built for you.

https://github.com/jinjor/elm-xml-parser is a good option. I believe it's used by the elm-xml-decode package you mentioned internally.

Here's an example of how you might have Elm take a string of html and output Elm's own version of Html using jinjor/elm-xml-parser (the `xmlToHtml` function in particular shows how you might "walk down the tree" structure that is output by the `XmlParser`):

```
import Html as H
import XmlParser

xmlToHtml : XmlParser.Node -> H.Html Never
xmlToHtml xmlNode =
    case xmlNode of
        XmlParser.Element tag attributes children ->
            -- do any mapping of the xml tag or attribute to what you want here!
            H.node tag [] (List.map xmlToHtml children)

        XmlParser.Text text ->
            H.text text


view : Model -> H.Html Never
view _ =
    let
        xml =
            """
            <arbitrary>
              <numberOfTagsHere>
                <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here. May contain <tag foo="bar">some text</tag></p>
                <p>Maybe another paragraph here.</p>
              </numberOfTagsHere>
            </arbitrary>
            """
    in
    Result.map
        (.root >> xmlToHtml)
        (XmlParser.parse xml)
        |> Result.withDefault (H.text "  Failed to parse the xml :(  ")
```

Comment: This is great. But how can I import Model? I'm trying to run it here in Ellie: https://ellie-app.com/7cyJrjYFyqRa1 and it complains that it can't find that type.

Comment: Model is just whatever type your application is using. You declare it yourself. Here's a functioning example of your Ellie with everything running: https://ellie-app.com/7cyXF9vXzHra1